# Coding for Re-use

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a solution to packaging code in node.js?

By this I mean...  We are evaluating using node.js along with express to develop a couple of web application.  All of these web applications will need code that preforms similar functionality.  For example, an Authentication module may consist of server-side.js, client-side.js, and views.  Is there a way to bundle those 3 files together in a manner so they can be easily added to any other project?

What are the most common practices or good ideas for developing with this code re-use idea in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a primer, take a look at the [Node Modules docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules).

Code single purpose packages and add them to your apps using

```
$ cd my_app
$ npm link ../some_module
$ npm link ../authentication_module
```

To use these modules in your code

```
// my_app/app.js
var someModule = require("some_module"),
    auth       = require("authentication_module");
```

Each module should have a valid `package.json` file. You can create it using using

```
$ cd some_module
$ npm init
```

---

If your modules are suited for others to use, you can also publish them to http://npmjs.org

```
$ cd some_module
$ npm publish
```

Then, you can use that module in your app as

```
$ cd my_app
$ npm install --save some_module
```

---

If a module is only needed for development, you can install a module using (mocha as example)

```
$ cd my_app
$ npm install --save-dev mocha
```

---

For additional resources, I highly encourage you to browse the packages on http://npmjs.org and see how others are authoring packages.

Here's a couple really popular ones

- https://github.com/caolan/async
- https://npmjs.org/package/request
- https://github.com/visionmedia/express
- https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha

Comment: Good info, thanks for the info maček.  My understanding is that with Require, you are referencing a single file.  So this would work great for separating the Server-side.js for Auth into its on file.  But then the Client-side.js and the View would still require manually moving those files.  Or are you saying with require you can actually include a directory that may have more than just one file?

Comment: @FLOODracer, that is correct. I highly encourage you to look at the [module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) documentation to see some other examples.